# TypeError: unhashable type: 'AddedToken'

Tags: python

I have a test.py file and I want to package this file using pyinstaller, but running the generated exe file produces the following error.

> None of PyTorch, TensorFlow >= 2.0, or Flax have been found. Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test.py", line 25, in 
> File "transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2024, in from_pretrained
> File "transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2256, in _from_pretrained
> File "transformers\models\bert\tokenization_bert.py", line 217, in **init**
> File "transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 367, in **init**
> File "transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 507, in _add_tokens
> File "transformers\tokenization_utils.py", line 512, in _update_trie
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'AddedToken'
> [3492] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!

test.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = [('./data/sb.csv', 'data')]
datas += copy_metadata('tqdm')
datas += copy_metadata('regex')
datas += copy_metadata('requests')
datas += copy_metadata('packaging')
datas += copy_metadata('filelock')
datas += copy_metadata('numpy')
datas += copy_metadata('huggingface-hub')
datas += copy_metadata('safetensors')
datas += copy_metadata('pyyaml')

a = Analysis(
    ['test.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=['transformers'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='test',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=False,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

I guess there is some conflict between transformers and pyinstaller, because I run the py program directly with no problem, but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Would it be possible to fix it by adding the following?
datas += copy_metadata('tokenizers')